# Does angular-cli uses rollup to do ahead-of-time compilation and adding all into one file?

Tags: angular-cli

I am wandering do angular-cli uses rollup to combine all the angular stuffs into one file by ahead-of-time compilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the bundling is being done with webpack.